# Wrong Last Modified Date in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transferutility

While uploading file one by one to AWS S3 bucket using Java code, I'm observing a strange issue with Last Modified Date column, all the files are showing same last modified date.  I followed few posted in StackOverFlow but no-where is properly mentioned on how to set user defied meta-data while storing file to S3.

I did like this in my code but didn't not work for me. Could you please suggest?

```
ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
metaData.setContentLength(bytes.length);
metaData.setHeader("x-amz-meta-last-modified", OffsetDateTime.parse(new Date().toString()).toLocalDate());
```

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.parse(new Date().toString())` will never work. Just use `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`.

Comment: I think the datetime format should be like: 2011-10-15T16:25:49.000Z else it won't be reflected.

Comment: if you have implemented the same, could you please guide me on how you have set "x-amz-meta-last-modified" in header?